# Can't Change the default theme on WordPress by BitnamI running on AWS

Tags: permissions, hosting, amazon

After installing a WordPress server on AWS using 'bitnami-wordpress-5.7.2' as the instance, now I am not able to change the default theme using the wp-admin. When I try to activate or live preview a theme, the default theme is displayed and no change is observed.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Bitnami on AWS is configured for some extreme security and in the past when I've attempted to use it I've become extremely frustrated with the permissions configuration and the fact that Bitnami don't really offer up much support. If you do figure this out I encourage you to post your solution here and even write a blog post about it and link it so that other people can get access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the permissions of the `wp-content` and `wp-content/themes` folders? They should be 755 (`owner=write, group=read, public=read`).

If, for some reason, the user on your instance that runs the webserver (probably www or www-data) is not the owner of that directory but in the group that owns that directory it should be 775 (`owner=write, group=write, public=read`)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I did change the permissions to 775 but still can't change the theme or live preview it. the permissions are as bellow:                                                                                                                                           
______                                                                                                                                                          
drwxrwxr-x  7 bitnami daemon 4096 Jun  5 22:22 themes